# (Tomcat Apache configurations)can't see Tomcat Apache landing page

Tags: apache, jsp, debian, tomcat7

Actually, I'm new to Linux and its configurations. I just installed Tomcat Apache 7.0.52 on my debian linux. I entered IP`192.168.56.10`, the server ip, but it shows `it works!` page which means the older version of apache server:Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) is running, not tomcat, the correct page should contain tomcat's logo. Is there any configurations I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Check the server.xml. Tomcat's port is normally 8080, if you have not changed it. So please try the IP with the port: 192.168.56.10:8080

This defines the port, where the server listens:

```
 <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: I checked but it's the same, no difference

Comment: Just verified with NetBeans and a local installation on a windows system: The default port is 8084.

Comment: Do you mean the 8084 port?

Comment: Strange. Are you able to shut down the Apache webserver (not tomcat)? Try to play around with tomcat's port and see if something changes. Don't forget to restart the tomcat server.